# How to specify the port to map to on the host machine when you build the image wiith Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I run Docker from command line I do the following:

```
docker run -it -d --rm --hostname rabbit1 --name rabbit1 -p 127.0.0.1:8000:5672 -p 127.0.0.1:8001:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

I publish the ports with -p in order to see the connection on the host.
How can I do this automatically with a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant specify ports in Dockerfile but you can use docker-compose to achieve that.

[Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is a tool for running multi-container applications on Docker.

example for docker-compose.yml with ports:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services :
  rabbit1:
    image : mongo
    container_name : rabbitmq:3-management
    ports: 
      - 8000:5672
      - 8001:15672
```

Comment: Anything for the IP?

Comment: you don't need to specify the localhost IP address, even in docker run also

Comment: What if I wanted to change the IP

Comment: You have to open the port from the firewall for outside access. when mapping ports we map docker host port to container port (host_port: container_port). read more about port mapping in here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Answer (score 4):

The Dockerfile provides the instructions used to *build* the docker image.

The `docker run` command provides instructions used to *run* a container from a docker image.

> How can I do this automatically with a Dockerfile

You don't.

Port publishing is something you configure only when starting a container.